# Find property then replace all its values - lodash

Tags: javascript, arrays, lodash

I have an array of objects:

```
users = [
  {userId: 23, userName:"foo"},
  {userId: 34, userName:"wrong"},
  {userId: 45, userName:"baz"},
  {userId: 56, userName:"..."},
]
```

Lets say I want to find all objects with the property of userName and replace the value with updatedUser:

```
updatedUser = {"foo"}
```

so in this case I will end up with a new array like:

```
users = [
  {userId: 23, userName:"foo"},
  {userId: 34, userName:"foo"},
  {userId: 45, userName:"foo"},
  {userId: 56, userName:"foo"}
]
```

I am using lodash but dont mind native.

Any help please?

Comment: do you want the same array or a new one?

Comment: New array would be best in my case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could assign a new object with the wanted value.

```js
var users = [{ userId: 23, userName: "foo" }, { userId: 34, userName: "wrong" }, { userId: 45, userName: "baz" }, { userId: 56, userName: "..." }],
    update = { userName: "foo" },
    result = users.map(o => Object.assign({}, o, update));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Why you need lodash, you can do it simply like following.

```
users.forEach((el)=>{el.userName= "foo";})
```

```js
users = [
  {userId: 23, userName:"foo"},
  {userId: 34, userName:"wrong"},
  {userId: 45, userName:"baz"},
  {userId: 56, userName:"..."}
]

users.forEach((el)=>{el.userName = "foo";})
console.log(users);
```

Still if you prefer using `lodash`, you can try like following.

```
_.setProperty( users, 'userName', 'foo' );
```

Answer (score 0):

you can users `Array.prototype.map` and override the userName field for each element

```js
const users = [
  {userId: 23, userName:"foo"},
  {userId: 34, userName:"wrong"},
  {userId: 45, userName:"baz"},
  {userId: 56, userName:""}
];

const result = users.map(u => ({...u, userName: "foo"}));
console.log(result);
```